# Routing not working properly in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm developing a small angular project with three components.Is that project I have a sub module called component.module and I have added added routing in that module and  component.module includes to  App.module.

**It's compiling without any error but nothing display on screen** (see image below).

[image]

My project folder structure is like this.

[image: folder structure]

**components/app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { MainLayoutComponent } from "./main-layout/main-layout.component";
import { IntentListComponent, IntentCreateComponent } from "./intent";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "home",
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "list", component: IntentListComponent },
      { path: "create", component: IntentCreateComponent }
    ]
  } 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**components/component.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { MainLayoutComponent } from "./main-layout/main-layout.component";
import { IntentCreateComponent, IntentListComponent } from "./intent";

import { ProjectCreateComponent } from "./project";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainLayoutComponent,
    IntentCreateComponent,
    IntentListComponent,
    ProjectCreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class ComponentModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { ComponentModule } from "./components/component.module";



@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,

    ComponentModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<app-main-layout></app-main-layout>
```

**app/components/main-layout/main-layout.component.html**

```html
<div class="side-bar">
</div>
  
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't export anything from your `ComponentModule` module, then importing it in your `AppModule` won't give it anything from the `ComponentModule`.

Since you're using `Routing` and `MainLayoutComponent` from your `ComponentModule` in your `AppModule`, you'll have to add these to the `exports` array of the `ComponentModule` as well.

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { MainLayoutComponent } from "./main-layout/main-layout.component";
import { IntentCreateComponent, IntentListComponent } from "./intent";

import { ProjectCreateComponent } from "./project";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainLayoutComponent,
    IntentCreateComponent,
    IntentListComponent,
    ProjectCreateComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [AppRoutingModule, MainLayoutComponent]
})
export class ComponentModule {}
```

**PS:** If you want to use anything from your `ComponentModule` into your `AppModule`, you'll have to export it from your `ComponentModule` by adding it to the `exports` array of your `ComponentModule`.

Answer (score 3):

Just add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in app.component.html and after configuring routing as explained above

Answer (score 2):

Your routes configuration should be something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "home",
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", component: IntentListComponent },
      { path: "create", component: IntentCreateComponent },
  ]
  }];
```

or

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", pathMatch: "full" },
  {
    path: "home",
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "list", component: IntentListComponent },
      { path: "create", component: IntentCreateComponent },
      { path: "", redirectTo: "list" pathMatch: "full" }
  ]
  }];
```

As your component is loaded, but there is nothing in the view. But as for your configuration if you route to /home/list or /home/create that component will be loaded

Answer (score 1):

If the component module is a feature module, then you must write:

```
RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

instead of

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```